# How to paste R script together to generate one Notebook?

Tags: r, rnotebook

I have several R scripts, say `a.R`, `b.R`, `c.R`. I want to paste all scripts together to one file and then use this file to generate a Notebook.

In `a.R`, the code is

```
#' This is some text in a.R to be used in Notebook.
dat1 <- 1:10
```

In `b.R`, the code is

```
#' This is some text in b.R to be used in Notebook.
dat2 <- dat1
```

In `c.R`, the code is

```
#' This is some text in c.R to be used in Notebook.
dat3 <- dat2
```

I want to have an overall file `all.R` and it should look like this:

```
#' This is some text in a.R to be used in Notebook.
dat1 <- 1:10
#' This is some text in b.R to be used in Notebook.
dat2 <- dat1
#' This is some text in c.R to be used in Notebook.
dat3 <- dat2
```

I could also manuelly copy everything together, but I do not want to because I will lose an overview of everything. I am wondering whether there is any more elegent way?

Comment: You could use `source('a.R');source('b.R')... ` in the last script

Comment: But if I use `source`, I can not generate a Notebook as shown in `all.R` @Waldi

Comment: OK, thanks for your feedback, I understand & read too quickly your question ;)

Comment: The notebook is markdown?

Comment: @Waldi Yes, I want to have an Rmd file actually.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`child`](https://yihui.org/knitr/demo/child/) knitr chunck option:

````
---
title: "Notebook"
output: html_document
---

```{r insertScriptA, child = 'ScriptA.Rmd'}
```

```{r insertScriptB, child = 'ScriptB.Rmd'}
```
````

Comment: The point is, without `a.R` I am not able to run `b.R` and thus I am not able to generate `b.Rmd`. Therefore I cannot generate a Rmd file as you suggested. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for my own use.

I use a system command to concatenate every R scripts together to another R script `all.R` and then I convert `all.R` to `all.Rmd`. I use linux.

Here is how I did it in R only:

```
library(knitr)
#cat is a command under linux to concatenate files. The first command is used to generate all.R.
system("cat a.R b.R c.R > all.R") 
spin("all.R") # Convert all.R to all.Rmd
```